# How to use this javascript code with eval or in a iim file?

Tags: javascript, eval, imacros

I want to use this code with eval or in a iim file without using js file.I tried for using it into eval but didn't work.Or is there any other way that can allow this code into iim file directly? please help me!

```
do {
do {
    iimPlay("CODE:ondialog pos=1 button=ok content=\nrefresh");
} while (iimGetLastError(1) != "OK");
iimPlay("CODE:set !timeout_step 1\ntag pos=1 type=input attr=name:verification_type&&value:code_voice");
} while (iimGetLastError(1) != "OK");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without Eval there is no way to using javascript code inside iim file.